# Installing Steam games on a RAID 0 array

Tags: steam, raid, mdadm

So I just put a few old drives in a RAID 0 using mdadm and it was originally just for STeam games, but when I hit install, I don't know how to make it download onto my RAID 0 array... So is there a way to do that? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

## Using a Symlink

1. Mount your RAID array somewhere (like `/media/tank`)
2. Close Steam
3. Move `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/` to your RAID array.

   `mv ~/.steam/steam/steamapps /media/tank/steamapps`
4. Make a symlink

   `ln -s /media/tank/steamapps ~/.steam/steam/steamapps`
5. Start Steam and install some games.

## Using Steam

Sometimes Steam detects mountpoints and shows them in the install dialog.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNutQ.png)

Mount your RAID array somewhere and it should appear.

Comment: Great I'll try that but I do have one small problem... The array is shown in Disks but not in mdadm... Look at this: http://imgur.com/eCqtYXe

Comment: Sorry, I don't know too much about RAID. What happens if you try to mount /dev/md0 somewhere? (You might have to make a filesystem on it first.)

Answer (score 0):

Your raid device is /dev/md0.
If you haven't done it already, you need to format it.
for exemple

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
```

Then you can mount it :

```
mkdir /media/tank
mount /dev/md0 /media/tank
```

then follow Matthew's instructions.